# Adding a key to a multidimensional array from another multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have seen lots on adding to multidimensional arrays but I can't figure out how they apply to my situation. I am trying to end up with one large multi-dimensional array.

I have a multidimensional associative array compiled from a mysql query of a membership database. All my arrays are compiled using while loops.

```
Array(
     [0] => Array ( [full_name] => Amy Smith [id] => 00111111 [member_ref] => 1 [type] => 1 ) 
     [1] => Array ( [full_name] => Bob Smith [id] => 00222222 [member_ref] => 2 [type] => 0 ) 
     [2] => Array ( [full_name] => Cam Smith [id] => 00333333 [member_ref] => 3 [type] => 2 ) 
     )
```

This was compiled from the mysql_query

```
SELECT full_name, id, member_ref, type 
FROM members 
ORDER BY full_name asc
```

I then have a list of [id] numbers in another table for people who have paid membership. This is provided by another organisation. This will become the [paid] key.

```
Array(
      [0] => Array ( [id] => 00111111 ) 
      [1] => Array ( [id] => 00333333 ) 
      [2] => Array ( [id] => 00444444 ) 
     )
```

From query:

```
SELECT * FROM paid
```

And finally a table that counts members attendances within a specified timeframe, to be the [log] key.

```
Array(
 [0] => Array ( [member_ref] => 1 [COUNT(member_ref)] => 17 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [member_ref] => 2 [COUNT(member_ref)] => 10 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [member_ref] => 3 [COUNT(member_ref)] => 1 )
     )
```

From

```
SELECT member_ref, COUNT(member_ref) 
FROM log 
WHERE timestamp >= STR_TO_DATE('$from') 
AND timestamp < STR_TO_DATE('$to') 
GROUP BY member_ref
```

What i want to end up with is: (Note that Bob Smith hasn't paid)

```
 Array(
     [0] => Array ( [full_name] => Amy Smith [id] => 00111111 [member_ref] => 1 [type] => 1 [paid] => 00111111 [log] => 17) 
     [1] => Array ( [full_name] => Bob Smith [id] => 00222222 [member_ref] => 2 [type] => 0 [paid] => 0 [log] => 10) 
     [2] => Array ( [full_name] => Cam Smith [id] => 00333333 [member_ref] => 3 [type] => 2 [paid] => 00333333 [log] => 1) 
      )
```

I can then output it as necessary, but crucuially I can sort the data by any of the keys.

I am open to doing this with a single mysql query with the sort key being a php $var, but I can't figure out the JOIN elements, it's just far too complex for me to understand.

Thanks

Comment: there's no need for `str_to_date()` if your date is already in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. MySQL can understand that directly. You only need `str_to_date()` if your date string is in a non-standard format, like `Jul 31, 2014` or whatever.

Comment: so for paid, you either want there Id or zero?  why not a 0 or 1 or true of false?

Comment: Marc - If it ain't broke...

Comment: NSjonas they are all fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from the answer of NSjonas:

```
   SELECT m.full_name,
          m.id,
          m.member_ref,
          m.type, 
          (p.id IS NOT NULL) paid,
          COUNT(l.member_ref) log
     FROM members m
LEFT JOIN paid p
       ON m.id = p.id
LEFT JOIN log l
       ON m.member_ref = l.member_ref
      AND l.timestamp >= '$from' 
      AND l.timestamp < '$to'
 GROUP BY m.full_name, m.id, m.member_ref, m.type, p.id
 ORDER BY m.full_name ASC
```

Comment: yup yours is a bit cleaner and more correct, good job.  I haven't been writing sql for almost a year now.  a little rusty with the syntax

Comment: @NSjonas, thanks I tried editing your answer.. but I think it got lost somewhere.. as you did most of the work, if your answer gets corrected and accepted I'll delete this one.

Comment: Yea i made my own edit before i saw that so it got automaticly refused.

Comment: your use of (p.id IS NOT NULL) is better than my case statement, so i think its a valid (better) answer anyways.  Is the group by necessary?

Comment: @NSjonas Ok, I don't know about the GROUP BY, I'd probably put it in just for readability, I'd have to test it to be sure.

Comment: yea, I wasn't sure either but it might be.  Mine might just return the total number of rows for the entire table.  Like I said... its been a while

Comment: @Arth there is a bug. It doesn't show people who  have 0 entries in the log table, which it needs to.

Comment: Fixed - changed the WHERE to AND

Answer (score 1):

My mySQL is a bit rusty but I think this is basically what your looking for.  Definitely possible in 1 query

```
SELECT m.full_name, m.id, m.member_ref, m.type, COUNT(l.member_ref) log,
Case WHEN p.Id != null
 THEN true
 ELSE false paid
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN paid p 
ON m.id = p.id
LEFT JOIN log l
ON m.member_ref = l.member_ref
WHERE l.timestamp >= STR_TO_DATE('$from') 
AND l.timestamp < STR_TO_DATE('$to')
ORDER BY m.full_name asc
```

Comment: actually looks like I misunderstood the "paid key".  I assumed you only wanted members who paid. Let me try again

Comment: If it helps the error generated is `near 'INNER JOIN paid
ON members.id = paid.id
INNER JOIN log
ON members.member_ref' at line 3`

Comment: @SLV opps, I refactored based and missed that line

Comment: @SLV hey man, I think you need to refresh your page and look at either my updated answer or the answer by arth.  My first attempt was not correct and you want to use LEFT join instead of INNER joins so that you always select all records from the Members table.

Comment: Thanks. I was refreshing I don't know what happened. Thanks for your help.